# Why are Java Errors swallowed on threads spawned by an ExecutorService instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I thought Java Errors were indications of serious problems and shouldn't be handled. Why then, does this code run fine?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> {throw new AssertionError();});
    while (!future.isDone()) {
    }
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

I had an unimplemented method which threw an AssertionError to remind me to implement it but it just got swallowed up with absolutely no indication that something was seriously wrong.

Comment: How do you propose this current thread should handle an exception thrown at an arbitrary time in the other thread, do you think it should interrupt this current thread? As aka-one points out, you can get the exception in the other thread with a call to `Future.get()`

Comment: A slight variant of @xtratic's comment : generally speaking, the thread that submits the work to execute could even be gone (terminated its run method) by the time the exception is thrown. So, either you actually check the error status (`isDone`only checks that the task ended, not if it ended normally), or you supply your own `ExceptionHandler` to the threads

Comment: @xtratic I'm not talking about Exceptions, I propose that if an Error is thrown anywhere the system should fail-fast and exit like it does with uncaught exceptions.

Comment: @Someguy but `Error`s, generally speaking, do not terminate a java application. An OutOfMemoryError does not. An error just bubbles up the stack, until it is caught, or kills its thread if it is not caught. Once there is no non dameon thread, the JVM quits, but if there are other, it continues. Errors do not "make the JVM exit", in and of themselves.

Comment: @Someguy I should have said `Throwable`. An `Error` shouldn't necessarily kill everything. A thread could have an `Error` but other threads might be able to keep on going. I would really hate if what you're suggesting is the way it was, taking control away from the developers and just killing the processes would suck.

Comment: @xtratic I mean I am speaking from a position of inexperience and slight irritation after trying to work out why my runnable was appearing to do absolutely nothing when I was submitting it to be run so my proposals shouldn't be taken seriously anyway. It seems that if you are going to handle certain Errors though, why aren't those Errors just Exceptions.

Comment: @Someguy I think the main thing is what the types of `Throwable`s communicate to the catcher, `Errors` communicate that there is a pervasive issue in the process that isn't just some invalid condition. But just because there is an issue like this in one thread doesn't mean you should kill all threads and you still have a chance of recovering if you want to try.

Answer (score 6):

It's not swallowed, it's there:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> {
            throw new AssertionError();
        });
        while (!future.isDone()) {
        }
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }
```

You get the error on calling **get** method that gives you the result of computation if succeeded or an error otherwise.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  ...

Comment: Why would  someone call get on the Future returned by a Runnable? The point of submiting a Runnable is that you want a procedure run which doesn't return a value

Comment: @Someguy your comment is logically perfectly valid. But the API that is given to you is to call get() to have the result of the computation. Result is broader than what you might expect though: did it end, did it end normally or exceptionnaly, was it cancelled, did it even start or was it cancelled before ? If you think about concurrent programming, these are all valid (part of the) definition of what the result is.

Comment: Yes. Concurrent programming rarely makes sense the first time, I guess :-). Or maybe any time, for that matters.